# LEFT JOIN returning non-related data where it should be NULL

Tags: mysql

I have 7 tables I'm trying to join together.

**Post**

```
+------+--------+--------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------+---------+
| Id   | commid | author |        created        |        updated        |   title   | content |
+------+--------+--------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------+---------+
|   80 |     16 |    7   | 2019-07-27 23:11:07   | 2019-07-27 23:11:07   | Lorem     | Ipsum   |
|   79 |     16 |    7   | 2019-07-27 23:09:47   | 2019-07-27 23:09:47   | Lorem     | Ipsum   |
|   78 |     16 |    7   | 2019-07-27 23:09:09   | 2019-07-27 23:09:09   | Lorem     | Ipsum   |
|   77 |     16 |    7   | 2019-07-27 23:08:36   | 2019-07-27 23:08:36   | Lorem     | Ipsum   |
|   76 |     16 |    7   | 2019-07-27 23:03:17   | 2019-07-27 23:03:17   | Lorem     | Ipsum   |
|   75 |     16 |    7   | 2019-07-27 22:38:48   | 2019-07-27 22:38:48   |           |         |
+------+--------+--------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------+---------+
```

**Community**

```
+----+----------------+
| ID |     title      |
+----+----------------+
| 16 | The Scary Door |
+----+----------------+
```

**Community Tag Categories**

```
+-----------+----------+
| Community | Category |
+-----------+----------+
| 16        | 5        |
+-----------+----------+
| 16        | 18       |
+-----------+----------+
| 16        | 19       |
+-----------+----------+
| 16        | 20       |
+-----------+----------+
```

**Tag Category**

```
+-------------+----+
| category    | Id |
+-------------+----+
| character   | 5  |
+-------------+----+
| focus       | 18 |
+-------------+----+
| warning     | 19 |
+-------------+----+
| Time-period | 20 |
+-------------+----+
```

**Tag Categorised**

```
+----------+-----+
| category | Tag |
+----------+-----+
| 5        | 146 |
+----------+-----+
| 19       | 147 |
+----------+-----+
| 20       | 148 |
+----------+-----+
```

**Tag**

```
+---------------+-----+
| name          | Id  |
+---------------+-----+
| spider        | 146 |
+---------------+-----+
| arachnophobia | 147 |
+---------------+-----+
| Victorian era | 148 |
+---------------+-----+
```

**Post Tags**

```
+------+-----+
| post | Tag |
+------+-----+
| 80   | 146 |
+------+-----+
| 80   | 147 |
+------+-----+
| 80   | 148 |
+------+-----+
```

There are some posts which do no have corresponding information in some of the tables therefore I have tried to use LEFT JOINs. This is the query I have been trying to use:

```
SELECT p.id, c.id as 'commid', c.title AS 'community', p.author, p.created, p.updated, tc.category, t.name AS 'tag', p.title, p.content
FROM Post p
INNER JOIN Community c
ON p.community=c.id
AND c.id=16
LEFT JOIN CommunityTagCategories cc
ON c.id=cc.community
LEFT JOIN TagCategory tc
ON cc.category=tc.id
LEFT JOIN TagCategorised ct
ON tc.id=ct.category
LEFT JOIN Tag t
ON ct.tag=t.id
LEFT JOIN PostTags pt
ON t.id=pt.tag
GROUP BY p.id, t.id
ORDER BY p.created DESC;
```

Since only post 80 has any associated tags there should be three entries for the three tags on post 80, and one entry for the other posts with no tags. Like this.
I don't actually care what the category is for the posts with NULL tags, I would just like one row for those posts.

**Result I want**

```
+----+--------+----------------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+---------------+-------+----------+
| Id | commid |   community    | author |       created       |       updated       |  category   |      tag      | title | content  |
+----+--------+----------------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+---------------+-------+----------+
| 80 |     16 | The Scary Door |      7 | 2019-07-27 23:11:07 | 2019-07-27 23:11:07 | character   | spider        | Lorem | Ipsum    |
| 80 |     16 | The Scary Door |      7 | 2019-07-27 23:11:07 | 2019-07-27 23:11:07 | warning     | arachnophobia | Lorem | Ipsum    |
| 80 |     16 | The Scary Door |      7 | 2019-07-27 23:11:07 | 2019-07-27 23:11:07 | time-period | victorian era | Lorem | Ipsum    |
| 79 |     16 | The Scary Door |      7 | 2019-07-27 23:09:47 | 2019-07-27 23:09:47 |             | NULL          | Lorem | Ipsum    |
| 78 |     16 | The Scary Door |      7 | 2019-07-27 23:09:09 | 2019-07-27 23:09:09 |             | NULL          | Lorem | Ipsum    |
| 77 |     16 | The Scary Door |      7 | 2019-07-27 23:08:36 | 2019-07-27 23:08:36 |             | NULL          | Lorem | Ipsum    |
| 76 |     16 | The Scary Door |      7 | 2019-07-27 23:03:17 | 2019-07-27 23:03:17 |             | NULL          | Lorem | Ipsum    |
| 75 |     16 | The Scary Door |      7 | 2019-07-27 22:38:48 | 2019-07-27 22:38:48 |             | NULL          |       |          |
+----+--------+----------------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+---------------+-------+----------+
```

However, when I run the query I get 24 results with data that repeats 4 rows for each post. with every single tag including NULL. Like this (but with every post, not just the two posts I'm showing here).
It also shows a tag category that is not being used with any posts (`Focus`) and I'm not sure why that is there.

**Actual result**

```
+----+--------+----------------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+---------------+-------+----------+
| Id | commid |   community    | author |       created       |       updated       |  category   |      tag      | title | content  |
+----+--------+----------------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+---------------+-------+----------+
| 80 |     16 | The Scary Door |      7 | 2019-07-27 23:11:07 | 2019-07-27 23:11:07 | character   | spider        | Lorem | Ipsum    |
| 80 |     16 | The Scary Door |      7 | 2019-07-27 23:11:07 | 2019-07-27 23:11:07 | focus       |               | Lorem | Ipsum    |
| 80 |     16 | The Scary Door |      7 | 2019-07-27 23:11:07 | 2019-07-27 23:11:07 | warning     | arachnophobia | Lorem | Ipsum    |
| 80 |     16 | The Scary Door |      7 | 2019-07-27 23:11:07 | 2019-07-27 23:11:07 | time-period | victorian era | Lorem | Ipsum    |
| 79 |     16 | The Scary Door |      7 | 2019-07-27 23:09:47 | 2019-07-27 23:09:47 | character   | spider        | Lorem | Ipsum    |
| 79 |     16 | The Scary Door |      7 | 2019-07-27 23:09:47 | 2019-07-27 23:09:47 | focus       |               | Lorem | Ipsum    |
| 79 |     16 | The Scary Door |      7 | 2019-07-27 23:09:47 | 2019-07-27 23:09:47 | warning     | arachnophobia | Lorem | Ipsum    |
| 79 |     16 | The Scary Door |      7 | 2019-07-27 23:09:47 | 2019-07-27 23:09:47 | time-period | victorian era | Lorem | Ipsum    |
+----+--------+----------------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+---------------+-------+----------+
```

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but have you tried filtering for Community ID through a WHERE clause instead of inside the Inner Join?

Comment: It is impossible to reconruct your statement, you have columns that not correspond with the tables you given. this is what i got Select pt.post,p.Id,c.Community, p.misc,c.title,tcd.Tag, t.name 
from posts p inner 
join Communnity c on p.community = c.Community
left join CommunnityTagCategories ctc on p.community = ctc.Community
Left Join TagCategory tc on ctc.Category = tc.id
Left Join TagCategorised tcd ON tcd.category = tc.ID
Left join Tag t ON t.Id =  tcd.Tag
Left join PostTags pt ON pt.Tag = t.Id
GROUP BY p.id, t.id;

Comment: I tried putting the WHERE c.id=16 just before the GROUP BY part at the end but it gave me the same 24 results.

Comment: @nbk Sorry I realised I'd written one column name wrong in the community table (community->id). The misc column is just the various columns from the Post table (author, created, updated, title, content etc. that I just truncated into misc. I tried your query where you changed the LEFT JOIN of Community to CommunityTagCategories ON p.community=ctc.id instead of c.id=ctc.id but it gave me the same result.

Comment: show me in the dbfiddle if you can show me what you got https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=528793b4c34e2826510a62171940c1e2

Comment: This shows the 24 results with the non-relevant category 'focus' https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=077212e375ed0dd0e0c8bd8280dfe00a

Comment: Sorry. I just realised my question might have been unclear on what results I wanted

Comment: i tried every combination,but the db design is against it. without filtering focus  the best i came with is the first select after the create block https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=1986f6126d35529de16191a4502f49ca

Comment: Thank you for trying! Since it's too late to change the database design I decided to try getting around the issue by creating a NULL tag and linking to that for posts without tags (as well as linking to a random tag category). When I did that it worked with a different mysql query.

Comment: This is the code that gave me the correct results: SELECT p.id, p.title, p.content, p.author, p.created, p.updated, ct.category, t.name AS 'tag'
FROM Post p, Community c, CommunityTagCategories cc, TagCategory ct, TagCategorised tc, Tag t, PostTags pt
WHERE c.id=18 AND p.community=c.id AND c.id=cc.community AND cc.category=ct.id AND ct.id=tc.category AND tc.tag=t.id AND t.id=pt.tag AND pt.post=p.id
ORDER BY p.created DESC;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much thinking about it. I came with a solution that should get you the wished
Result

```
Select 
  p.Id, max(p.author) author, max(p.community) community, max(p.created) created
  ,max(p.title) title , max(p.content) content
  ,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT (cttc.category)) category
  , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT (ctatc.name)) Tag
From 
  Post p 
  inner Join Communnity c On c.Id = p.CommId
  right Join (
    Select cc.Community, tc.category, tc.Id
    From 
      TagCategory tc 
      inner join CommunnityTagCategories cc 
    ON cc.Category = tc.Id) cttc  
  ON p.Commid = cttc.Community
Left join (
  Select 
    p.post,t.name,ct.category
    From 
      PostTags p 
      inner join Tag t ON t.Id = p.Tag 
      inner join TagCategorised ct ON ct.Tag = t.Id
  ) ctatc  
  ON ctatc.category = cttc.id and ctatc.post = p.id
GROUP BY p.Id;
```

it gets you

> Id     author  community   created     title   content     category    Tag
>
> 75     7       The Scary Door  2019-07-27 22:38:48             warning,character,Time-period,focus
> 76  7   The Scary Door  2019-07-27 23:03:17     Lorem   Ipsum   character,Time-period,focus,warning
> 77  7   The Scary Door  2019-07-27 23:08:36     Lorem   Ipsum   focus,warning,character,Time-period
> 78  7   The Scary Door  2019-07-27 23:09:09     Lorem   Ipsum   warning,character,Time-period,focus
> 79  7   The Scary Door  2019-07-27 23:09:47     Lorem   Ipsum   character,Time-period,focus,warning
> 80  7   The Scary Door  2019-07-27 23:11:07     Lorem   Ipsum   warning,character,Time-period,focus     arachnophobia,spider,Victorian era

[DBfille example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=02283cacad01efeb65ff3a15dee5bbf0)

Comment: Wow, this is really good! Thank you. It will require a bit of changing the PHP code to work with this new format but it seems to get everything I want. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be with the database design so I decided to try getting around the issue by creating a NULL tag and linking to that for posts without tags (as well as linking the NULL tag to a random tag category for that community).

When I did that it worked with this mysql query:

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, p.content, p.author, p.created, p.updated, ct.category, t.name AS 'tag' 
FROM Post p, Community c, CommunityTagCategories cc, TagCategory ct, TagCategorised tc, Tag t, PostTags pt 
WHERE c.id=18 AND p.community=c.id AND c.id=cc.community AND cc.category=ct.id AND ct.id=tc.category AND tc.tag=t.id AND t.id=pt.tag AND pt.post=p.id 
ORDER BY p.created DESC;
```