# Select all posts (and associated tags) that are tagged with a search

Tags: mysql

I want to select posts (and their tags) that are tagged with one or more search term.

Here are my tables:

**Post**

```
| ID | community | created             | updated             | title | content |
|----|-----------|---------------------|---------------------|-------|---------|
| 99 | 17        | 2019-08-14 14:20:38 | 2019-08-14 14:20:38 | Lorem | Ipsum   |
| 80 | 16        | 2019-07-27 23:11:07 | 2019-07-27 23:11:07 | Lorem | Ipsum   |
| 79 | 16        | 2019-07-27 23:09:47 | 2019-07-27 23:09:47 | Lorem | Ipsum   |
```

**Community**

```
| ID | title          |
|----|----------------|
| 16 | The Scary Door |
| 17 | Other          |
```

**Community Tag Categories**

```
| Community | Category |
|-----------|----------|
| 16        | 5        |
| 16        | 18       |
| 16        | 19       |
| 16        | 20       |
| 17        | 6        |
```

**Tag Category**

```
| category    | ID |
|-------------|----|
| character   | 5  |
| focus       | 18 |
| warning     | 19 |
| time-period | 20 |
| NULL        | 6  |
```

**Tag Categorised**

```
| category | tag |
|----------|-----|
| 5        | 146 |
| 6        | 131 |
| 6        | 147 |
| 19       | 147 |
| 20       | 148 |
```

**Tag**

```
| name          | id  |
|---------------|-----|
| spider        | 146 |
| arachnophobia | 147 |
| Victorian era | 148 |
| NULL          | 131 |
```

**Post Tags**

```
| post | tag |
|------|-----|
| 99   | 147 |
| 80   | 146 |
| 80   | 147 |
| 80   | 148 |
| 79   | 131 |
```

I'm already using this query to get information on all posts and their associated tags and categories:

```
SELECT p.id, c.id as 'commid', c.title AS 'community', p.title, p.content, p.author, p.created, p.updated, ct.category, t.name AS 'tag'
FROM Post p, Community c, CommunityTagCategories cc, TagCategory ct, TagCategorised tc, Tag t, PostTags pt
WHERE p.community=c.id AND c.id=cc.community AND cc.category=ct.id AND ct.id=tc.category AND tc.tag=t.id AND t.id=pt.tag AND pt.post=p.id
ORDER BY p.created DESC;
```

If I search for a tag like 'arachnophobia' I would like the results to be narrowed down like this: (and if I wanted to search for 'arachnophobia' AND 'spider' it should  only display the information for post 80)

```
| ID | commid | community      | title | content | author | created             | updated             | category    | tag           |
|----|--------|----------------|-------|---------|--------|---------------------|---------------------|-------------|---------------|
| 99 | 17     | Other          | Lorem | Lorem   | 7      | 2019-08-14 14:20:38 | 2019-08-14 14:20:38 | NULL        | arachnophobia |
| 80 | 16     | The Scary Door | Lorem | Lorem   | 7      | 2019-07-27 23:11:07 | 2019-07-27 23:11:07 | character   | spider        |
| 80 | 16     | The Scary Door | Lorem | Lorem   | 7      | 2019-07-27 23:11:07 | 2019-07-27 23:11:07 | warning     | arachnophobia |
| 80 | 16     | The Scary Door | Lorem | Lorem   | 7      | 2019-07-27 23:11:07 | 2019-07-27 23:11:07 | time-period | Victorian era |
```

From searching similar questions it seems like I might need to use a nested SELECT and INNER JOINS. I tried doing that like this:

```
SELECT p2.id, c.id as 'commid', c.title AS 'community', p2.author, p2.created, p2.updated, p2.title, p2.content, tc.category, t.name AS 'tag' 
FROM 
    (SELECT p.id
    FROM Post p, Tag t, PostTags pt
    WHERE p.id=pt.post AND pt.tag=t.id AND t.name ="arachnophobia"
    ) search
INNER JOIN Post p2
ON (search.id = p2.id)
INNER JOIN Community c
ON p2.community=c.id
INNER JOIN CommunityTagCategories cc
ON c.id=cc.community
INNER JOIN TagCategory tc
ON cc.category=tc.id
INNER JOIN TagCategorised ct
ON tc.id=ct.category
INNER JOIN Tag t
ON ct.tag=t.id
INNER JOIN PostTags pt
ON t.id=pt.tag
INNER JOIN Post p3
ON pt.post=p3.id
ORDER BY p2.created DESC;
```

It does return only results for posts 99 and 80 but it gives me results for every single tag and category that exists in their associated communities, even when those posts are not associated with those tags and categories. 
So here it returns an extra row for post 80 with the tag from post 79 which are both in the same community.

```
| ID | commid | community      | title | content | author | created             | updated             | category    | tag           |
|----|--------|----------------|-------|---------|--------|---------------------|---------------------|-------------|---------------|
| 99 | 17     | Other          | Lorem | Lorem   | 7      | 2019-08-14 14:20:38 | 2019-08-14 14:20:38 | NULL        | arachnophobia |
| 80 | 16     | The Scary Door | Lorem | Lorem   | 7      | 2019-07-27 23:11:07 | 2019-07-27 23:11:07 | character   | spider        |
| 80 | 16     | The Scary Door | Lorem | Lorem   | 7      | 2019-07-27 23:11:07 | 2019-07-27 23:11:07 | warning     | arachnophobia |
| 80 | 16     | The Scary Door | Lorem | Lorem   | 7      | 2019-07-27 23:11:07 | 2019-07-27 23:11:07 | time-period | Victorian era |
| 80 | 16     | The Scary Door | Lorem | Lorem   | 7      | 2019-07-27 23:11:07 | 2019-07-27 23:11:07 | character   | NULL          |
```

I asked a similar question about displaying all post data a few days ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57418663/left-join-returning-non-related-data-where-it-should-be-null) and user nbk helped out with a different query that also works, but it's a little too complicated for me to know how to alter myself.

Answer (score 1):

For avoid duplicated rows you could use DISTINCT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p2.id
  , c.id as commid
  , c.title AS community
  , p2.author
  , p2.created
  , p2.updated
  , p2.title
  , p2.content
  , tc.category
  , t.name AS tag 
FROM  (
   SELECT p.id
   FROM Post p
   INNER JOIN PostTags pt ON p.id=pt.post
   INNER JOIN Tag t ON  pt.tag=t.id AND t.name ="arachnophobia"
) search
INNER JOIN Post p2 ON search.id = p2.id
INNER JOIN Community c ON p2.community=c.id
INNER JOIN CommunityTagCategories cc ON c.id=cc.community
INNER JOIN TagCategory tc ON cc.category=tc.id
INNER JOIN TagCategorised ct ON tc.id=ct.category
INNER JOIN Tag t ON ct.tag=t.id
INNER JOIN PostTags pt ON t.id=pt.tag
INNER JOIN Post p3 ON pt.post=p3.id
ORDER BY p2.created DESC;
```

Just some suggestions.

You should not use single quote around  column name (this if for literal text) use  backticks when needed.

Should not use old implicit join syntax  based  table name comma separated  and where condition (you have in your subquery).

Avoid unnecessary () around join condition.

And looking to your relation: you should avoid the last part of join for tag you have already obtained by search.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p2.id
  , c.id as commid
  , c.title AS community
  , p2.author
  , p2.created
  , p2.updated
  , p2.title
  , p2.content
  , tc.category
  , t.name AS tag 
FROM  (
    SELECT p.id
    FROM Post p
    INNER JOIN Tag t ON p.id=pt.post AND t.name ="arachnophobia"
    INNER JOIN PostTags pt ON pt.tag=t.id 
) search
INNER JOIN Post p2 ON search.id = p2.id
INNER JOIN Community c ON p2.community=c.id
INNER JOIN CommunityTagCategories cc ON c.id=cc.community
INNER JOIN TagCategory tc ON cc.category=tc.id
INNER JOIN TagCategorised ct ON tc.id=ct.category
ORDER BY p2.created DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you. I had to swap around the two INNER JOIN tables in the nested SELECT query to make it work properly. Unfortunately it's still giving me results with  unrelated tags. E.g. If post 96 in community 16 is tagged with 'cat' then it returns a row for post 80 with that tag, even when post 80 isn't tagged with that.

Comment: I had heard about using INNER JOINs is better than the the basic SELECT FROM WHERE queries, but that query returns many duplicate rows compared to the query I have now.

Comment: The current query for all posts gives me 21 results but the INNER JOIN query  returns 315 results (SELECT p.id, c.id as 'commid', c.title AS 'community', p.title, p.content, p.author, p.created, p.updated, ct.category, t.name AS 'tag'
FROM Post p
INNER JOIN Community c
ON p.community=c.id
INNER JOIN CommunityTagCategories cc
ON c.id=cc.community
INNER JOIN TagCategory ct
ON cc.category=ct.id
INNER JOIN TagCategorised tc
ON ct.id=tc.category
INNER JOIN Tag t
ON tc.tag=t.id 
INNER JOIN PostTags pt
ON t.id=pt.tag
INNER JOIN Post p2
ON pt.post=p2.id
ORDER BY p.created DESC;)

Comment: your comments are not clear  to me ... waht do you mean for duplicate  row ..  in your sample (above your query)  which are the duplicated  rows .. i don't see duplicated ...  eventually just updated ..  your question adding for a simple sample 
 your actual result  .. you expected  result (and the query you have used)

Comment: Sorry I added the actual results above, does that help? Post 79 is tagged with NULL and post 80 is showing as having the tag NULL even though it doesn't. So it's giving me extra rows for the posts with tags they aren't tagged with. The INNER JOIN query and both my nested SELECT and your nested SELECT are giving me these irrelevant results.

Comment: you mean    post  99 ??  (not 79)

Comment: No, sorry. Post 99 is tagged with arachnophobia in the NULL category. The last row is the one I mean. Post 80 is showing as having the tag NULL under a random category. It's taking the NULL tag from post 79 which isn't associated with Post 80 but it still shows the ID as post 80.